# max_allowed_packet could not be set in MySQL 5.5.25

Tags: mysql, database

I could not set "max_allowed_packet" variable in MYSQL command prompt though I can set this value by inserting "max_allowed_packet=100M"  line into my.ini file. Why I am having following warning?

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+---------+
| Variable_name      | Value   |
+--------------------+---------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1048576 |
+--------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> warnings
Show warnings enabled.
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=123456000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect max_allowed_packet value: '123456000'
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+---------+
| Variable_name      | Value   |
+--------------------+---------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1048576 |
+--------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I have alse tried smaller size as following.

```
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=123456;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect max_allowed_packet value: '123456'
mysql>

mysql> set session max_allowed_packet=123456;
ERROR 1621 (HY000): SESSION variable 'max_allowed_packet' is read-only. Use SET GLOBAL to assign the value
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect max_allowed_packet value: '123456'
Error (Code 1621): SESSION variable 'max_allowed_packet' is read-only. Use SET GLOBAL to assign the value
```

**MySQL Version**

```
    mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 1.1.8                        |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.5.25                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86                          |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22891 and http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32223
where the conclusion was that max_allowed_packet should be a startup parameter only.

Answer (score 8):

I noticed that you have to use multiples of 1024 for the values to be accepted:

A value of 2048001 fails:

```
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=2048001;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect max_allowed_packet value: '2048001'
```

But a value of 2048000 works:

```
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=2048000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) says the following, but it seems that the 'rounding down' does not work as designed:

> The value should be a multiple of 1024; nonmultiples are rounded down
>   to the nearest multiple.

Comment: I does not give an  error when trying 2048000, but changes do not ocured.SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';

Answer (score 4):

The [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111324/5791928)
and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111324/5791928) are good check them out. Adding to those, when we start MySQL server we get a **global deafult** `max_allowed_packet` value and when a connection to server is initialized this global deafult `max_allowed_packet` value is copied to a **local**  `max_allowed_packet` variable (which is read only) and used by connection for its operations.

So basically after every server restart you need to enter

> set global max_allowed_packet=1048576000;

Drop all the connections and start new connections, so that this new global value is reflected and now you would be able to insert blob.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't logging out and back in!